# ToolTip on Mouse Hover in DataGrid View Window's Form Application

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have a window's form on which I insert datagridview which has two columns `(Id,Name)`.I want when mouse hover over cells of datagridview,`Sales` related to particular `Id` is shown as a tooltip.Each `Id` has different `Sales`.This `Sales` come from database against each `Id`.Kindly help me,how to achieve this in vb.net.

Comment: Thanks,but i want it in window's form application,not web form application

Comment: Cheers, added Winforms tag.

Comment: can you tell me how to get value of datagridview column on mouse hover?

Comment: Sales has to be in the datasource or you are out of luck.  you only mention `ID and Name` for the DGV

Comment: Sales is in the same table,but i want it to be shown as tooltip rather than column

Comment: you are going to have to add a ToolTip component, perhaps run a query in the hover event (ugh!), then set the tooltip text.  A DGV can have columns which are invisible, so if Sales was in the query/dataset, you'd just have to post it to the tooltip text in the hover event.  The easiest thing is just to add it to the DGV - they user either wants/needs to see it or not. see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795659/tooltip-on-datagridview

Comment: Thanks i done it my self

Answer (score 0):

in VB forms, you simply set the cells tooltip value

```
 DataGridView1.Rows(1).Cells(1).ToolTipText = ""
```

in asp.net you might use a template field within your grid

```
 </asp:TemplateField><asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Saleslist"  HeaderStyle-Font-Size="Small" ><ItemTemplate ><asp:Label ID="lbl_theIDtext" runat="server" Text='<%# EVAL("id") & " " & EVAL("Sales") %>' ToolTip ='<%# EVAL("SalesInfo") %>' ></asp:Label></ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:
- The property "ShowCellToolTips" is set to false

```
Private Sub dgvMyName_ToolTip(sender As Object, e As 
DataGridViewCellToolTipTextNeededEventArgs) Handles dgvMyName.CellToolTipTextNeeded
  If sender Is Me.dgvMyName Then
  If e.RowIndex > -1 AndAlso 
     e.RowIndex < Me.dgvMyName.Rows.Count 
     AndAlso Me.dgvMyName.Rows(e.RowIndex).DataBoundItem IsNot Nothing Then
    e.ToolTipText = "My Tooltip Text"
  End If
End Sub
```